# VM Domino server reading Excel data works while RDP session is active

Tags: excel, lotus-domino, ibm-domino

Windows Server 2008 R2

Domino 901 FP10

I have this line in my Domino agent. Set to run every 15 minutes. Below is the line in question.

```
Set xlsApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

If I have an open RDP session to the server. This runs fine either on schedule or by command line execution.

Once I close the RDP session, each scheduled run returns this:

> Error # 208 - Cannot create automation object

I had to modify my DCOM properties for Excel to get this to work on the server in the first place. Any idea what to try to get this to run "unattended".

Thank you for reviewing!

Answer (score 0):

On our servers we have created folder `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop` (for x64) or `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop` (for x86). Just create folder only!

Then creating excel instance and save worksheet works fine.

We have this advice saved for years in our internal wiki. But without any details. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, Lukas, I do have that folder created based on some other posts. It didn't seem to help the fact that the excel instance seems to require an interactive session.